# updating "multiple" columns of "selected" rows of a data table with duplicate key values

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a data table with a million odd rows. It has a non-unique key. One particular column(say v1) has NA for few rows. I need to update this column(v1) and another column(v2) when v1 has NA. Values for updating these columns come from another data table. The following code simulates the datasets:

```
set.seed(1)
DT1<-data.table(
        id1=c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), 
        id2=c("a", "e", "n", "e", "e", "c"), 
        v1=c(rnorm(1), rep(NA,2),  rnorm(1), NA, rnorm(1)), 
        v2=rnorm(6))
setkey(DT1, id2)

DT2<-data.table(id2=c("n","u", "e"), v1=c(1, 2, 3), v2=c(11, 22, 33))
setkey(DT2, id2)
DT1; DT2
```

After update DT1 will look as:

```
> DT1
   id1 id2         v1         v2
1:   1   a -0.6264538  1.5952808
2:   2   c -0.8356286  0.5757814
3:   1   e          3         33
4:   2   e  0.1836433  0.4874291
5:   2   e          3         33
6:   1   n          1         11
```

Please note that row#4 is not updated as v1 has a value.

I tried the following code, but it updates all the matching rows (including row#4)

```
DT1[DT2[unique(DT1[is.na(v1), id2]),nomatch=0], c("v1","v2"):=list(i.v1,i.v2)]
```

If I provide a filter to the above code (given below), DT1 remains unchanged.

```
DT1[is.na(v1)][DT2[unique(DT1[is.na(v1), id2]),nomatch=0], c("v1","v2"):=list(i.v1,i.v2)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

And What would be a more elegant way of writing R/data.table code for such a problem?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
DT1[is.na(v1), c("v1", "v2") := DT2[.SD[["id2"]], list(v1, v2)]]
#   id1 id2         v1         v2
#1:   1   a -0.6264538  1.5952808
#2:   2   c -0.8356286  0.5757814
#3:   1   e  3.0000000 33.0000000
#4:   2   e  0.1836433  0.4874291
#5:   2   e  3.0000000 33.0000000
#6:   1   n  1.0000000 11.0000000
```

Comment: Nice approach! I think you will need `.SD$id2` instead of just `id2`... It just happens to work in this case IIUC

Comment: @Arun I was a bit unsure about scoping rules there. Don't have time to investigate, so I simply trust you. :)

Comment:  sure. It will be less confusing once we have a way tor clearly referring to variables outside the scope of DT. But we have been saying that for a while now..

Comment: @Arun, can you please explain importance of .SD$id2 as mentioned by you? It will help my understanding better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kishore, sure. `DT2[id2, ..]` will use `id2` column from `DT2`, whereas what you really need is the `DT1`'s `id2`, which can be accessed with `.SD` (which stands for subset of data). In this case, since there's no grouping, `.SD == DT1`. So you could also do `DT1$id2`.. Does that help?

Comment: Oops.. You should use .SD, sorry. Because we filter for NA in v1... .SD will contain only those rows and is what you need and will not be equal to DT1... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do `DT1[is.na(v1), .SD]` to see the result and things should be clear.